# Can xcpretty print comments which included in test scenarious?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I'm wonder if there is an option in xcpretty to print in HTML report comments which I left in my test cases? 
I run xcpretty like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace example-example.xcworkspace -scheme "example-example" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 (10.3.1) [9C14ED59-D6E2-4E85-8662-007080BC27F1]" -derivedDataPath "./output" test|xcpretty --report html
```

I try to google it, but no success for me.

Main idea is to have some describing of what happens in test to people, who didn't write this code.